# How can I set the color of asp:table Caption?

Tags: css, asp.net, webforms

I'm using asp:Table on webforms pages that have a background image.  The problem I'm trying to solve is: the CAPTION that I put on the table(s) is nearly un-readable because it blends in with the background too much.   I have tried setting ForeColor="White" directly as well as css containing (color:white).  Those only have effect on the table CONTENTS not the Caption.  All the searches I've done on this only talk about table Content or Headers - which is Not what I care about.   Any hope?

Comment: Could you provide some codes please?

Comment: @Maziar - Code isn't needed for anyone to understand my question.  Re-read it, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In near all such cases, one can apply a style sheet.

So, say this markup:

```
        <style>
            .MyTable 
                {background-color:lightsteelblue}
            .MyTable caption {
                background-color:steelblue;
                color:white
            }
        </style>

        <asp:Table ID="Table1" runat="server"
            CssClass="MyTable table" Width="40%"
            Caption="Test Caption" GridLines="Both"
            >
            <asp:TableRow>
                <asp:TableCell>
            Row 0, Col 0
                </asp:TableCell>
                <asp:TableCell>
            Row 0, Col 1
                </asp:TableCell>
            </asp:TableRow>
            <asp:TableRow>
                <asp:TableCell>
            Row 1, Col 0
                </asp:TableCell>
                <asp:TableCell>
            Row 1, Col 1
                </asp:TableCell>
            </asp:TableRow>

        </asp:Table>
```

And the result is this:

[image]

So, using a style for both background, and "caption" background can be done with above. And of course, since I did for this example set the background color of the caption area, then I also set the font color.

I should note the 2nd class called "table" is the bootstrap table class, and I find they tend to do a really great job of spacing out the table.

If I remove the bootstrap "table" class.

eg this:

```
CssClass="MyTable table"
```

To just our class, eg this:

```
CssClass="MyTable"
```

Then the table comes out like this:

[image]

So, I do often recommend adding that class "table", since it will make the table responsive, and also does a great job of spacing it out. However, doing so will require you to then set the width, since the table will expand to 100% width when you add that bootstrap "table" class.